# Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered + Async storage error

Tags: react-native, expo

When I try running my app with `npx expo start`, it displays this error:

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I have tried deleting the node modules folder and the package-lock.json file. I ran `npm install` after doing that and nothing seems to be working. These are the contents of my AppEntry.js file:

import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';

import App from '../../App';

registerRootComponent(App);

I also get this error when trying to run my app:

> Invariant Violation: AsyncStorage has been removed from react-native core. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage, js engine: hermes

I have installed the new Async storage, but I've heard that that won't do the trick. I think I have to update all the imports in my app, which I'm trying to find an automatic way of doing.

Any help with these errors?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.